# Javascript function will run and automaticly removed after 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im creating an API for my Website Project.
I have made some Javascript functions that will be run at `.ready()`.

So the first Code which will run is for my `<table>` using DataTable.js.
The Ajax Section is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#ticketTable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "api.php?getTickets",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
```

after that (but still in `.ready()`)
I call my `GetTotalUsers` function like this:

```
$('#totalUsers').replaceWith(GetTotalUsers());
```

And the `GetTotalUsers` function looks like this:

```
function GetTotalUsers() {
    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api.php?getUsers&count",
        success: function(text) {
            response = text;
        }
    }); 
    return response;
}
```

My Problem now is, that if I press F5 the Code will run and is half-sucessfully.
Why I am saying that? Because for 1 second I can see that `#totalUsers` will contain the Number 5 (Total Users) but after that 1 second it will be removed and then there is just nothing.

So im askins, isn't it possible to have multiple Ajax Requests at the same time?
Why can I see the TotalUsers for just 1 second ?
Why Totalusers will be removed after 1 second ?

Comment: `response` in the `GetTotalUsers()` function is a `jqXHR` object, not a DOM Element or jQuery object, so I'm not sure exactly what you want to append to the DOM there but I can tell you it's most likely not what you expect it to be.

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the `GetTotalUsers()` method for multiple sides. Not Only for the id tag `#totalUsers`. But the thing is when it wouldn't work because it is an `jqXHR` why I see the result then (just for 1 minute but I see it) ? I guess i can do something like that?: `GetTotalUsers('#totalUsers');` and for  the function: `GetTotalUsers(content) {  [...] $(content).replaceWith(text) }` or ?

Answer (score 1):

Like Rory and Kaddath said in the comments, the `response` in my Question is an `jqXHR`. So I decided to fix it this way:

```
GetTotalUsers('#totalUsers');

GetTotalUsers(content) {
    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api.php?getUsers&count",
        success: function(text) {
            $(content).replaceWith(text);
        }
    });
}
```

But why can I see the result of my Questions Code for 1 second if it wouldn't work for normal?